# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "my-volume" : references non-existent secret key: keyfile

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Trying to deploy an app with volume that holds a json file for a secret to be accessible by the pod.

I created a secret that holds a json file (my-keyfile.json) with

kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file=my-keyfile.json

When I describe the secret, I get

```
Name:         my-secret
Namespace:    otoko
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
gd-hosting-production-4bb83363d2c2.json:  2383 bytes
```

Added a pod environmental variable

```
- name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  value: /home/appuser/gcp-pubsub-subscriber-keyfile.json
```

Here is my config for the volume

```
  volumes:
    - name: my-volume
      secret:
        secretName: my-secret
        items:
          - key: keyfile
            path: my-keyfile.json

volumeMounts:
      - name: my-volume
        mountPath: /home/appuser/my-keyfile.json
        subPath: my-keyfile.json
        readOnly: true
```

But getting the following error

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "my-volume" : references non-existent secret key: keyfile
```

And the app cannot find the my-keyfile.json file located at /home/appuser/my-keyfile.json

Comment: Are you using GKE?

Comment: Can you check if the provided [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netcoolomnibus/8?topic=mbpkihc-troubleshooting) is helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mismatch between your filename and volume spec. In the secret you have `gd-hosting-production-4bb83363d2c2.json` key whereas in volume spec you reference `my-keyfile.json`. Is that a typo?

Anyways try using this:

```
  volumes:
    - name: my-volume
      secret:
        secretName: my-secret
        items:
          - key: my-keyfile.json
            path: my-keyfile.json

volumeMounts:
  - name: my-volume
    mountPath: /home/appuser/my-keyfile.json
    subPath: my-keyfile.json
    readOnly: true
```

Don't forget to replace the filename with what you have in the secret.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the error message: `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "my-volume" : references non-existent secret key: keyfile`

1. The error says you messed something up in `my-volume` so we know where to look.
2. Later, it tells us that a `key` named `keyfile` doesn't exist in the secret.
3. We look at the definition of `my-volume` to check what secret is defined there.

   ```yaml
   volumes:
     - name: my-volume
       secret:
         secretName: my-secret
   ```
4. We check `my-secret` and we see it has 1 entry:

   `gd-hosting-production-4bb83363d2c2.json:  2383 bytes`

> Note: `Key` is the name of the field, `Value` is what it contains.

5. There is no `keyfile` key in your secret. Only `gd-hosting-production-4bb83363d2c2.json`
6. Change your volume definition to reference the correct key:

   ```yaml
   volumes:
     - name: my-volume
       secret:
         secretName: my-secret
         items:
           - key: gd-hosting-production-4bb83363d2c2.json
             path: my-keyfile.json
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation break down.